# How can I determine the Lindblad operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm studying the energy transfer in the [FMO complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenna%E2%80%93Matthews%E2%80%93Olson_complex) theoretically, so I need to solve the Lindblad master equation. The problem is that I don't know how to get the Lindblad operators. Can I treat it as a two level system?

Comment: What does FMO stand for? Asking how to find the Lindblad operators is like asking us how to find the Hamiltonian of your system - if you don't know them already then you don't know what your system is.

Comment: I know the Hamiltonian of the system but I have some difficulties to apply the Lindblad equation on the FMO complex(it's protein contain 7 chlorophylls)

Comment: This is an interesting problem that I too am thinking about (not specifically for your particular model, but in general). I think however that you'll need to provide a bit more information about how your quantum-mechanical model of this very large molecule is constructed. Like, what are the set of states you're using to model the system?